# Bookshelf / knex sorting with descending order then limiting results

Tags: promise, bluebird, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm looking to reverse and limit results. Reversing works fine, limiting works fine, but chained together, the results aren't how I expect. If limit is set to 10 I get 0 results. If it's set to 200 I get 6 results. Any idea what's causing this?

`Users
      .query(q => {
          q.orderBy('id', 'DESC').limit(10)
      })
      .fetch({withRelated: ['groups']})
      .then(function(users) {
          util.filterUsers(users.map(function(user) {
              var groups = user.related('groups');
              return {
                  id: user.id,
                  handle: user.get('handle'),
                  githubid: user.get('githubid'),
                  name: user.get('name'),
                  public: user.get('public'),
                  url: user.get('url_hash'),
                  image: user.get('image'),
                  email: user.get('email'),
                  groups: groups.reduce(function(prev, group) {
                      prev[group.id] = group.get('group_name');
                      return prev;
                  }, {}),
              };
          }), req.user.id)
      .then((results) => {
          res.status(200).send(results);
      });`

Comment: What is your `then(function(users) {...}` doing? What does it return?

Comment: Updated. someone else wrote the initial script, I'm just trying to add the sorting and limiting.

Answer (score 2):

Each `then()` is expected to return a promise itself. If a common value is returned Bluebird (Bookshelf's choice for Promises) turns it into a promise itself.

In your case the `then(function(users) {...})` is not returning anything, so it should be replaced by `tap(function(users) {...})`. See [tap](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/tap.html) on Bluebird documentation.

But **IF** `util.filterUsers(...);` transforms the list somehow and it is a promise itself, you **MUST** return it, so placing its invocation under a `return` statement: `return util.filterUsers(...);`. In this case it is possible that it returns **fewer** users than the amount requested (that's what filters usually do...).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a return statement before your function `util.filterUsers`. Try this

```
Users
      .query(q => {
          q.orderBy('id', 'DESC').limit(10);
      })
      .fetch({withRelated: ['groups']})
      .then(function(users) {
          return util.filterUsers(users.map(function(user) {
              var groups = user.related('groups');
              return {
                  id: user.id,
                  handle: user.get('handle'),
                  githubid: user.get('githubid'),
                  name: user.get('name'),
                  public: user.get('public'),
                  url: user.get('url_hash'),
                  image: user.get('image'),
                  email: user.get('email'),
                  groups: groups.reduce(function(prev, group) {
                      prev[group.id] = group.get('group_name');
                      return prev;
                  }, {})
              };
          }), req.user.id);
      })
      .then((results) => {
          res.status(200).send(results);
      });
```